# How to chain data from mysql like mongodb for passing as json to api

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, codeigniter

I have a few tables in my **MySQL** database which are interconnected with foreign keys and I want to retrieve data from these for my **REST API**. So far I am successfully able to do it but I want to **chain/group** data from **MYSQL** for my **REST API**. Currently, I am getting my data like this

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":[
      {
         "floor_id":"1",
         "fk_client_id":"1",
         "floor_name":"first",
         "floor_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:06",
         "floor_active":"1",
         "room_id":"1",
         "fk_floor_id":"1",
         "fk_type_id":"1",
         "room_number":"101",
         "room_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:44",
         "room_active":"1"
      },
      {
         "floor_id":"1",
         "fk_client_id":"1",
         "floor_name":"first",
         "floor_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:06",
         "floor_active":"1",
         "room_id":"4",
         "fk_floor_id":"1",
         "fk_type_id":"2",
         "room_number":"104",
         "room_created_on":"2018-07-08 17:49:35",
         "room_active":"1"
      },
      {
         "floor_id":"3",
         "fk_client_id":"1",
         "floor_name":"third",
         "floor_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:21",
         "floor_active":"1",
         "room_id":"3",
         "fk_floor_id":"3",
         "fk_type_id":"3",
         "room_number":"301",
         "room_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:21:26",
         "room_active":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

[Demo Link of the current response format](https://getyourjson.com/index.php/api/data/4663026)

But I believe this is not the right approach, as you can see **Floors** data is being repeated for each **Room** and also this structure might be difficult to parse at the client side. I have worked with API data from MongoDB and I think a similar structure would be the best one for my data but I have no idea how to do it using **MYSQL** and **PHP**.

I have formatted the JSON which is given below myself to show how I need the response to be.

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "floors":[
         {
            "floor_id":"1",
            "fk_client_id":"1",
            "floor_name":"first",
            "floor_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:06",
            "floor_active":"1",
            "rooms":[
               {
                  "room_id":"1",
                  "fk_floor_id":"1",
                  "fk_type_id":"1",
                  "room_number":"101",
                  "room_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:44",
                  "room_active":"1"
               },
               {
                  "room_id":"4",
                  "fk_floor_id":"1",
                  "fk_type_id":"2",
                  "room_number":"104",
                  "room_created_on":"2018-07-08 17:49:35",
                  "room_active":"1"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "floor_id":"3",
            "fk_client_id":"1",
            "floor_name":"third",
            "floor_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:20:21",
            "floor_active":"1",
            "rooms":[
               {
                  "room_id":"3",
                  "fk_floor_id":"3",
                  "fk_type_id":"3",
                  "room_number":"301",
                  "room_created_on":"2018-07-07 05:21:26",
                  "room_active":"1"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

[Demo Link of the required response format](https://getyourjson.com/index.php/api/data/4502232)

I am using **Php Codeigniter** framework and here is my data fetching method in model class:

```
public function getdata($client_id) 
{
    $this - > db - > select('*');
    $this - > db - > from('floor_tb');
    $this - > db - > order_by('floor_tb.floor_id');
    $this - > db - > join('room_tb', 'room_tb.fk_floor_id=floor_tb.floor_id');
    $this - > db - > where("floor_tb.fk_client_id", $client_id);
    $this - > db - > where("floor_tb.floor_active", '1');
    $this - > db - > where("room_tb.room_active", '1');

    $mytable = $this - > db - > get();

    if ($mytable) 
    {
        return $mytable - > result_array();
    } else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my code from api controller:

```
$data = $this - > Data_Model - > getdata($client_id);
  if (!$data) {
      $failmsg = array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'no data found');
      $this - > response($failmsg, 201);

  } else {
      $successmsg = array('status' => 'success', 'data' => $data);

      $this - > response($successmsg, 200);

  }
```

Could someone please help me to achieve the desired ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at MySQL 8's JSON_OBJECTAGG function?  it works with both JSON and non-JSON columns